# How to upload an object into S3 in Lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Can't seem to upload an object into S3 in Lambda. Everything works fine locally. No errors in logs that would show what's going wrong...

Code below:

```
console.log('Loading function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var param = {Bucket: 'flow-logs', Key: 'test-lambda-x', Body: 'me me me'};
    console.log("s3");
    s3.upload(param, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
    console.log('done');
    context.done();
};
```

Runs successfully w/o error, but the callback in s3.upload doesn't seem to be called. No object in bucket is created.

Verified IAM role permissions weren't a problem by granting full access, as well as testing out locally.

Output

```
START RequestId: d4847fdb-160c-11e5-8a8c-b555b123e14d
2015-06-18T22:53:29.750Z    d4847fdb-160c-11e5-8a8c-b555b123e14d    s3
2015-06-18T22:53:30.271Z    d4847fdb-160c-11e5-8a8c-b555b123e14d    done
END RequestId: d4847fdb-160c-11e5-8a8c-b555b123e14d
```

Comment: Why is the s3 object created a second time? (locally and globally)

Comment: I've got a complete working version explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631229/how-to-set-open-download-permissions-on-a-file-created-in-s3-with-amazon-lambda/33632736

Answer (score 46):

I suspect you are calling the `context.done()` function before `s3.upload()` has a chance to return.  If you move `context.done()` into the upload response code block, it should work.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var param = {Bucket: 'flow-logs', Key: 'test-lambda-x', Body: 'me me me'};
    console.log("s3");
    s3.upload(param, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else console.log(data);           // successful response

        console.log('actually done!');
        context.done();
    });

    console.log('done?');
    //context.done();
};
```

Comment: @KatharineOsborne If it worked, then please accept the answer. This helps others in the community.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog I would but I didn't ask the question ;-)

Comment: @KatharineOsborne I see. My Bad. :)

Comment: saved my *life :)