# Location of bokeh plot output following AWS lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bokeh

I would like to use the output from a lambda function that generates a bokeh html file for a webapp. I believe that outputs are stored in the /tmp file, but given that lambda is totally stateless I do not believe it is possible to retrieve from lambda following execution. Is there a workaround for the usual bokeh syntax:

```
output_file('foo.html')
```

so that the .html is sent somewhere (preferably an S3 bucket)?

If this is a generally poor way to go about the task of generating a bokeh plot and getting the html, I'm open to hearing a better way. Also, if anyone has a link to a repo with bokeh source files that work on the AWS linus AMI, that would be appreciated...

Comment: A quick look at the bokah.io api doc makes it appear as there being little choice but to deal with local filesystem IO.  In  general, a bad  idea for AWS Lambda.  Ideally the output can be held in memory and placed on S3.  But it appears Bokeh is a geared toward interactive use. Push comes to shove: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006874/how-do-you-write-to-the-file-system-of-an-aws-lambda-instance

Comment: Thanks, Rich. I ultimately decided against Bokeh for this reason, as well as the difficulty I was having getting dependencies that run on amazon linux AMI.